# 子コンポーネントのuseEffectを発火させないようにするには？

Tags: reactjs, react-jsx

React でウェブツールを作成しています。
親コンポーネントが別のものに変わったとき、子コンポーネントの useEffect が発火しないようにすることは可能でしょうか？

最小のサンプルを用意いたしました。
CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-kowalevski-lkdbx

```js
function ComponentA(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "pink" }}>
      <p>Component A</p>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function ComponentB(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "skyblue" }}>
      <p>Component B</p>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function CommonComponent() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect is running in CommonComponent.");
  }, []);
  return (<div>Common component.</div>);
}

function App() {
  const [ab, setAB] = React.useState(true);
  const ParentComponent = ab ? ComponentA : ComponentB;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={ab}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setAB(event.target.checked);
          }}
        />
        Switch A/B
      </label>

      <ParentComponent>
        <CommonComponent />
      </ParentComponent>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

「Switch A/B」を切り替えるたびに、 CommonComponent 内の useEffect が発火するため、コンソールに "useEffect is running in CommonComponent." と出力されます。
このとき、実際のアプリケーションではサーバーからデータの fetch を行っており、実行コストが高いです。
この useEffect は依存リストに空配列を設定している通り、本質的には親の影響を受けない処理内容のため、何らかの方法で useEffect の再実行を回避できないでしょうか？

なお、実際には、 ComponentA, B はフォームであり、 CommonComponent はいくつかのチェックボックスをまとめたフォームの一部です。

Answer (score 1):

既に解決済みの問題かもしれませんが、一応参考程度の回答を書かせて頂きます。

---

親コンポーネントが再レンダリングされた場合、子コンポーネントは必ず再レンダリングされるので、構造が兄弟コンポーネントに変えられない場合、そのままのコードでは難しいかと思います。

今回に関しては再レンダリングを防ぎたいわけではなく「重いfetchを一度だけ実行したい」とのことなので、[Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/) や [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) などの状態管理ライブラリを導入する方法もあります。

ただ今回の場合、質問文に書かれてる情報だけでは

1. `ParentComponent` の差し替えタイミングでは `useEffect` が実行されなくてよい
2. `CommonComponent` (とその大元の親、サンプルでは `App` )がレンダリングされた場合は一度実行したい

とのことですので、この `useEffect` は本来 `App` が行う責務なのではないでしょうか？

であれば、以下の様に独自フック(Custom Hook)の `useCommonStatus()` などを定義し、 `ParentComponent` と `CommonComponent` をレンダリングする責務のコンポーネント( `App` )で `useEffect` を行い、fetchしたデータを `CommonComponent` に渡せばいいかと思います。

独自フックの作成 – React
https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

```js
// 独自フック
function useCommonStatus() {
  const [common, setCommon] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect is running.");

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("useEffect completed.");
      setCommon([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  return common;
}

function ComponentA(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "pink" }}>
      <p>Component A</p>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function ComponentB(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "skyblue" }}>
      <p>Component B</p>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function CommonComponent(props) {
  return (<div>Common component values: {props.common ? props.common.join() : 'Loading...'}</div>);
}

function App() {
  const common = useCommonStatus();

  const [ab, setAB] = React.useState(true);
  const ParentComponent = ab ? ComponentA : ComponentB;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={ab}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setAB(event.target.checked);
          }}
        />
        Switch A/B
      </label>

      <ParentComponent>
        <CommonComponent common={common} />
      </ParentComponent>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```